# Many-to-Many: Model e Template Django

Tags: django, django-templates, jinja2

Possuo a seguinte situação:
- Orçamento
- Produto
- Itens do Orçamento

Procurei o relacionamento **Many-to-Many** em **Django** (1.10), até ai tranquilo, cria no **Template** um Multi-Select.
Mas se por acaso eu necessite, por exemplo, informar a quantidade do produto no *Itens Orçamento* no momento em que eu estiver cadastrando um novo *Orçamento*, não consegui associar esse tipo de relação, ainda mais com **Jinja**.

A ideia é ter uma tela de cadastro de orçamento, onde eu posso adicionar produtos (pode ser **showmodal** no html), podendo informar a quantidade, desconto, etc, e depois poder salvar tudo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não sei se entendi corretamente seu problema, mas usando "InlineFormSet" não resolve?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets

Além disso, não faria mais sentido: Orçamento - Item do Orçamento(Produto, Quantidade) - Produto.

Boa sorte ;)

---

[EDIT]

Uma sugestão é duplicar o valor do produto no Item do Orçamento, se o preço do produto mudar no futuro o orçamento vai mudar também, o que normalmente não é o caso.